# Get first cell value after finding column header

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the first cell value after finding the header.

Currently I have this:.

```
Dim uLimitRange As Range
Dim lLimitRange As Range
uLimitRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("upper limit", , xlValues, xlWhole)
lLimitRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("lower limit", , xlValues, xlWhole)

uLimit = Range("uLimitRange" & 1)
lLimit = Range("lLimitRange" & 1)
```

However, this is returning a "run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set for the first line of code.

Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim uLimitRange As Range
Dim lLimitRange As Range
Set uLimitRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("upper limit", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set lLimitRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("lower limit", , xlValues, xlWhole)

Set uLimit = uLimitRange.Offset(1)
Set lLimit = lLimitRange.Offset(1)
```

**Comments**:

1. When setting Range variables to precede the operation with the **Set** statement
2. If you want to move from a given range use the **Offset** procedure where `Offset([rows], [columns])`